# Magento product url linking

Tags: magento, url

I am new to magento ...I started working on an half built magento site, the product added in the back end is not getting redirected to the product page..

```
I have changed the url in the url rewrite .. Here are the details : 

Request path : abc.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/59/s/kiyama-90210-brown/

Target path : catalog/product/view/id/59

Redirect : Permanent (301)

But it is taking the path : abc.com/kiyama-90210-brown
```

and giving error .. Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

try

1) abc.com/index.php/kiyama-90210-brown

a) if the above url is working than enable url rewrite form  System>Configuration>General
    select Web / Search Engines Optimization > yes

2) after changing the url rewrite please run reindexing